# How can I maintain the same content on two blogs?

Tags: seo, content-management-system, search-engine, blogs

Can I have maintain same content in Wordpress and blogger blog? If yes how?

Now I have two blog sites and I am posting the same content in these blogs. I read a note that google didn't promote these blogs. Is there any option to maintain these two blogs with same content like giving canonical. If yes please let me know how to give canonical.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that without receiving a penalty. Having same content on multiple sites causes duplicate content and it WILL give you a penalty.